# MySQL - Django can not display greek characters

Tags: mysql, django, character-encoding, display

I have a problem setting mysql db to properly recognise greek characters in django.

**setting.py**

```
...
'OPTIONS': {
    'charset': 'utf8',
    'use_unicode': True,
 }
...
```

Instead of `utf8` in the `charset` I tried using `windows-1253` and `iso-8859-1` but with no results.

I have stored database records successfully in Greek via CMD, but when I try to do the opposite in CMD again via ORM I get strange characters.

Comment: Please do this, to see if it got stored correctly:  `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...`.  Greek (in utf8) hex should be 2 hex bytes:  `CExx` or `CFxx`.

Comment: Data are stored correctly in MySQL (visible via phpmyadmin), but i can not extract them properly via Django ORM. That happens only for international characters and not for ASCII. Database collation is utf8.unicode.ci

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django needs `client_encoding: 'UTF8'`.

That tells MySQL that your bytes are utf8.

Comment: How it's supposed to be specified? In the settings.py as a parameter of DATABASES?

Comment: @Serk No, it's a configuration which is directly applied via SQL: like that: `ALTER ROLE myprojectuser SET client_encoding TO 'utf8';`